# What does Batman throw at Bane while in the sewers?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

During the fight scene in the sewers in *The Dark Knight Rises*, Batman throws something, and sparks and smoke start to appear around Bane.

Batman is, indeed, aiming for *deception and theatricality*, but what exactly does he throw?

Comment: Given what Bane says afterwards about the league of shadows, I assume its the hallucinogenic drug from the first film; but both Batman and Bane are now immune. I can't remember exactly what Bane says though, or the name of the drug.

Comment: I think he throws the gun powder (remember Ra's al ghul teaching him about theatricality and deception) and i think he modified that to create some mini-explosive batarangs to cause distraction.

Comment: More importantly, I thought Batman had an arsenal of lethal weapons on his utility belt he could have used against Bane.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I assumed it was merely a simple pyrotechnic doo-hicky, nothing special, just designed to distract the opponent enough to give Batman time to either escape or pummel him.  Bane isn't that easily distracted, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. The thing that he throws is to distract Bane. But it's also used to confuse the enemy - remember in Batman Begins, Ras showed him the gun powder trick and then asked him to inhale that smoke before trying to find him among the other ninjas. This is because it was rather hard for Bruce to first get going when he first inhaled since the experience was new to him. What he was carrying was a chemical found in the blue flower; if inhaled,you will get distracted and hallucinate. That's why Bane says, "Powerful Agents to the uninitiated".

Comment: Actually Bane was referring to "Theatricality and deception"  The blue flower was essentially what was used to make Scarecrow's fear toxin.  What Batman threw was basically a flashbang grenade.